# Return Value duplicated with file_get_html function of simple_html_dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have a problem with the function `file_get_html` of the library `simple_html_dom`, if I use this function to parse an url once or two times, it works, but if I try a third time, it returns me the same result as for the second url  ?
Can some one help me ?

```
require_once 'lib/simple_html_dom.php';
$url = 'http://exemple.com';
$brands = file_get_html($url);
$url2 = $brands->find('#a-div a.brand', 2)->href; 
$models = file_get_html($url2); 
$url3 = $models->find('#a-div a.model', 0)->href; 
$series = file_get_html($url3); 
$url4 = $series->find('#a-div a.model', 0)->href;
```

Comment: Can you help us with your code ?

Comment: what code did you use???

Comment: Before using `file_get_html` again, be sure you clear all dom objects like this: `$brands->clear(); unset($brands);` and so on...

Comment: Don't wok, may be the problem is on the function clear() ?

Comment: I've tried this code, but it doesn't work
[code]
    require_once 'lib/simple_html_dom.php';
    $url = 'http://exemple.com';
    
    $brands = file_get_html($url);
    $url2 = $brands->find('#a-div a.brand', 2)->href;
    $brands->clear();
    unset($brands);
     
    $models = file_get_html($url2); 
    $url3 = $models->find('#a-div a.model', 0)->href; 
    $models->clear();
    unset($models);
    
    $series = file_get_html($url3); 
    $url4 = $series->find('#a-div a.model', 0)->href;
[/code]

Comment: @wYm35: You did use it like [`THIS`](http://pastebin.com/xDNMA21m) right ?

Comment: Well, I cant say more without checking the actual code... If you want, you can join me on chat to discuss it...

Comment: How to ? Sorry I'm novice ^^

Comment: Ow, Damn, you don't have enough reputation to join a chat room (you need at least 20)... So, maybe just try to post a snipet of your code so I check what's wrong...

Comment: `require_once 'lib/simple_html_dom.php';
$url = 'http://exemple.com';
$brands = file_get_html($url);
$url2 = $brands->find('#a-div a.brand', 2)->href; 
$brands->clear();
unset($brands);
$models = file_get_html($url2); 
$url3 = $models->find('#a-div a.model', 0)->href; 
$models->clear();
unset($models);
$series = file_get_html($url3); 
$url4 = $series->find('#a-div a.model', 0)->href;
$series->clear();
unset($series);
print urldecode($url2) . ' - ' . urldecode($url3) . ' - ' . urldecode($url4);`

Comment: Please, do not post long codes in the comments, instead edit your question or use pastebin.com for example... So, you say that it gives `$url4` the same as `$url3` ? are you sure they are not ?

Comment: Yes, I'am, I would get a `href` of the `a` tag on a web page, the variables `$url4` and `$url3` have a same value ?!

Comment: [Formatted code ^^](http://pastebin.com/tXdizvXV)

Comment: May be the problem is on the `clear()` function ? But when I've seen the function on `simple_html_dom.php`, I've not found any error ?!

Comment: Are you sure `$url4` is different from `$url3` ? Please check that manually...

Comment: Yes, because the url for getting content is not the same, at the line 9 I get the dom form `$url2` while at the line 14 I get the dom form `$url3`, even if the selector are the same, the url for getting content aren't [Code](http://pastebin.com/tXdizvXV)

Comment: Well, this is not a reason, both pages could contain some identical urls, that's why I'm asking you to check manually the html code to be sure...

Comment: No, in the DOM of the both pages, the html isn't the same

Comment: In my case, at the first page we find a list of Brands, and when you click on any Brand, it display the list of Models, then when you click on any Model, you will display a list of Series, Finally when you click on a Series you get a data-sheet, I would get all data-sheet and insert them into a DB automatically